# Azure Account - error when trying to login from Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm attempting to login to my Azure account inside Powershell using `Login-AzureRmAccount`and am met with this error:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: WinInet cannot redirect. This error code might also be returned by a custom 
protocol handler.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand
```

When executing `Login-AzureRmAccount`a browser window opens prompting me for my email address - once entered I'm redirected to GoDaddy sign-in as this is where our Office365 infrastructure is hosted.  After entering my password here and hitting enter, I get the above error.  Does this have to do with the GoDaddy redirect?

Comment: I would suggest trying on another PC\VM, preferably in another location

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -AllowRedirection
```

I have a script for logging into Office365 powershell which has that parameter.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.  I've tried with the AllowRedirection flag and received this error: "Add-AzureRmAccount : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AllowRedirection'."

Answer (score 0):

After closing Powershell and rebooting, I'm now able to connect without error.